# How to apply complex styles using CSSResource in GWT

Tags: css, gwt, cssresource

In my project I your CSSResource bundle to apply styles accros the project.

How do I apply more complex styles such as given in the [example](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss) ?

I do not manage to get the child style applied using x.setStyleName(refToCss.MenuBar()) and addStyleName(refToCess.MenuItem()).

In my case the second (child) style *MenuItem* just seems to be ignored.

I just use this menubar as example here. What I want to achieve is having multiple components with multiple states. E.g. .component1 .stateA, component2 .stateA ..  where state A has different visual appearance for component1 and component2.

(Actually as CSS should work).

Thanks in advance,
Wouter

Answer (score 0):

```
In my case the second (child) style MenuItem just seems to be ignored.
```

In order to ignore you should use

```
x.setStylePrimaryName(refToCss.MenuBar());
```

Comment: Thanks I know, I want to figure out how to not ignore the second style using CSSResource.

Comment: Have tried with getStyle() and then add  space + you style....and then add it as primary style.?